# WPF - How to Create timeline for clip video in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, video, clip

I want to crate custom progress bar that contain tool for create clip video like below image,
I want create this tool in wpf
please help me how to do this

please send me some link that help me.

[image: Clip Video]

Comment: You have enough reputation that you should know this is *way* too broad for stack overflow. We aren't here to write your code for you.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET please help me what to do.

Comment: What to do? *Try something*. There are no built in controls that come near that functionality, so you'll have to roll your own. Once you have started, you will be able to ask a *specific* question about a problem you encounter. Right now, it looks like you just want us to do the work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use these tow program sample

[sample 1](http://timeline.codeplex.com/)

[Sample2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240411/WPF-Timeline-Control-Part-I)

if these not used for you you mus write it.